# Do I have to use std::forward when passing arguments pack to another variadic template function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

How do I implement a function (foo) which passes a parameter pack to a function (bar) which finally passes that paramer pack to a class constructor?
This is the code:

```
template <typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args)
{
    MyObj obj(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    /* Do something with obj */
}
```

Do I have to implement foo as

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{ bar(args...); }
```

Or

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{ bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works? Yes, you do need `forward`.

Comment: You might like to read [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `forward`.  `forward` looks like this:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

(There is another overload of `forward`, but it is irrelevant here.)

For each element `Arg` of the template parameter pack `Args`, `Arg` can be either: (`T` is a non-reference type)

- `T&` if the argument is a non-const lvalue, so that the parameter is of type `T&`; or
- `const T&` if the argument is a const lvalue, so that the parameter is of type `const T&`; or
- `T` if the argument is an rvalue, so that the parameter is of type `T&&`.

In the first case, `forward<Arg>(arg)` instantiates to:

```
constexpr T& forward(T& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&>(t);
}
```

resulting in a non-const lvalue to be passed.

In the second case, `forward<Arg>(arg)` instantiates to:

```
constexpr const T& forward(const T& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<const T&>(t);
}
```

resulting in a const lvalue to be passed.

In the last case, `forward<Arg>(arg)` instantiates to:

```
constexpr T&& forward(T&& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

resulting in an rvalue to be passed.

In all three cases, the value category is preserved, and the value is forwarded with modification to `bar`.

If you don't use `forward`, you will be unconditionally passing an lvalue, which is not desired.